# python import_module function not loading package

Tags: python, python-import

I have below openstack rally code which is dynamically loading python modules from given path using below function.

```
def load_plugins(dir_or_file):
   if os.path.isdir(dir_or_file):
      directory = dir_or_file
      LOG.info(_("Loading plugins from directories %s/*") %
             directory.rstrip("/"))

      to_load = []
      for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, followlinks=True):
          to_load.extend((plugin[:-3], root)
                         for plugin in files if plugin.endswith(".py"))
      for plugin, directory in to_load:
         if directory not in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(directory)

         fullpath = os.path.join(directory, plugin)
         try:
            fp, pathname, descr = imp.find_module(plugin, [directory])
            imp.load_module(plugin, fp, pathname, descr)
            fp.close()
            LOG.info(_("\t Loaded module with plugins: %s.py") % fullpath)
         except Exception as e:
            LOG.warning(
                "\t Failed to load module with plugins %(path)s.py: %(e)s"
                % {"path": fullpath, "e": e})
            if logging.is_debug():
                LOG.exception(e)
   elif os.path.isfile(dir_or_file):
      plugin_file = dir_or_file
      LOG.info(_("Loading plugins from file %s") % plugin_file)
      if plugin_file not in sys.path:
         sys.path.append(plugin_file)
      try:
         plugin_name = os.path.splitext(plugin_file.split("/")[-1])[0]
         imp.load_source(plugin_name, plugin_file)
         LOG.info(_("\t Loaded module with plugins: %s.py") % plugin_name)
      except Exception as e:
         LOG.warning(_(
            "\t Failed to load module with plugins %(path)s: %(e)s")
            % {"path": plugin_file, "e": e})
         if logging.is_debug():
            LOG.exception(e)
```

This was working absolutely fine as till 2 days ago. Now I am not getting error but its not loading any classes as well.
I only the first log information is printed and its getting printed and the while looking for loaded classes it fails. from below ensure_plugins_are_loaded is internally calling above function.

```
 File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in _run
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rally/plugins/__init__.py", in    ensure_plugins_are_loaded
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rally/task/engine.py",  in validate
```

#### Update 1

I tried calling a simple importlib.import_module('/opt/plugins'). Still not error thrown from import_module but python still can't find loaded modules. I am trying to find modules using subs = cls.**subclasses**() which extends given subclass.

#### Update 2

I also tried to use the same code without creating bdist_egg package. 
Just did

> python setup.py develop

and it works fine. So i am not sure what is problem when using it with bdist_egg.

Comment: Did you move the file to a different directory?

Comment: No. I just created a package using python bdist utility.

Comment: @jmugz3: Please see my latest update. It works fine with setup.py develop mode but doesn't work with bdist_egg.